# Naming clipped layer according to the attributes of the mask layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, modis

I have calculated the dnbr for a fire season across a whole region, and I've clipped it using a mask.

The mask is a layer of ground survey plot locations because I want to find out the dnbr for each plot. Each plot has a number under the field 'ID'. I have clipped the dnbr to each plot location but has returned (over 100 of) these new clipped files as 'new_clip'and a number irrelevant to the plot number. So I can't see which dnbr matches to which plot. I would like the new clipped files to look something like 'ID_247_clip'.

I've done this via `Raster -> Extraction -> Clip raster by mask layer`: input is Whole Region dNBR, overlay is plot locations. Then I've clicked the `'Iterate over this layer'` button. It gives me exactly what I need, just with the wrong title for the clipped layers.

Is there a way to program the clip to name each layer according to the plot numbers in the ID field?

I've tried executing in batch mode but this doesn't work, as I only have one input and one overlay layer, whereas bulk seems to work for multiple input layers.
Also, a lot of the plot locations overlap, so I can't do anything like join by location.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots would sure help me visualize your issue!

Comment: Hi Stu thanks for replying, I have put a screenshot on there now! :)

Comment: Can you give us the GDAL/OGR console call? Hidden in the screenshot. Could help to provide a fix

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? Is the mask layer used a single layer(file)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach to solving your problem.

**Split Mask Layer**

Start by splitting the mask layer. This can be done in QGIS using `Split Vector Layer`. If you use the ID as the unique field to split on, this will generate a list of masks of the form ID_1, ID_2, ... You can create these in a variety of formats, but let's assume Geopackage (GPKG), and they have all been saved to a single directory.

**Bulk Clip Raster - inside QGIS**

You can then use `Clip raster by mask layer` in Batch mode.

For the `Mask layer`, select `Add Files by Pattern...`, and use *.gpkg on the directory from above.
[image]

For the output (`Clipped (mask)`), you can use `Calculate by Expression...`. I used the following formula for the expression, which puts the output file names in the same format as your question:

```
file_path(@MASK) + '/' + base_file_name(@MASK) + '_clip.tif'
```

Any other values you need (eg the `Input layer` can be selected once and then Autofilled in the batch interface.

**Bulk Clip Raster - outside QGIS**

Alternatively, `Clip raster by mask layer` is just a wrapper for the gdalwarp command line tool. So outside QGIS, you can use a batch file or command line to call the gdalwarp tool. For example, in Windows, a command line like the below, run in the directory where the mask files are saved will iterate through each mask, and create .tif files named ID_1_clip.tif, ID_2_clip.tif etc. (%~nf stands for the filename without extension)

```
for %f in (*.gpkg) do call gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -cutline %~nf.gpkg -cl %~nf -crop_to_cutline D:/path_to/input.tif %~nf_clip.tif
```

Comment: Or simply run `Clip raster by mask layer` inside QGIS in Batch mode: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html

Comment: Thanks @Babel - I have updated the answer to include this option