# How to split raster by individual polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, vector, splitting

I have two layers. The first one is a vector layer with a lot of polygons. The other one is a raster layer. I need to extract raster to many rasters by individual polygons of the vector layer.

I tried the option Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster by mask layer but just one raster was extracted and not of each polygon.

This is my code and the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange, should work.. What if you rename the raster layer in the layer list/tree to something else and adjust line two. Like `raster1`. And/or restart qgis and try again. Your raster isnt a WMS layer or some other remote service right?

Comment: i changed name by raster1.tif but they show me the same error, my raster is a an imager GeoTIFF

Comment: which model exactely? using each polygone isn"t possible i have i lot of should i use one layer composed by many polygons to split raster

Comment: Are they all singlepart polygons with good geometry?  It looks like you have a lot of polygons of potentially "interesting" shapes which might favor using selections to do the clips and then merging them together.

Comment: but the error of code has realtion with vector or raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a model with Vector Features input. It will then iterate over each polygon and clip the raster. Make sure to tick "Iterate over this layer..." when you execute the model:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This model seems that will be give the same results like extract by mask plugin, i mean will consider vectoe with many polygone like just one to split imagery

Comment: @resuk your comment is not clear

Comment: It will give one raster per polygon. If not you are using Vector Layer as input, and not Vector Features. Or havent ticked the iterate... box

Comment: yes it works good with the plugin split raster by mask also, i am interessted to code juste to give to each raster of the severals rasters the name of id polygone using to split it, i wich u understand me

Comment: Ok I understand. I dont think that is possible using a model, you need pyqgis. Another option is to rename all temp outputs after the model using pyqgis.

Comment: really ,have you any documentation about this option, or you to do it

Comment: rename after the split when found image overlay to a polygone take this id polygon and make it like name of raster

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your polygon layer has geometry errors.  Run the **Fix Geometry** tool, which is found in the *Processing Toolbox*.

Comment: i fixed geometry but the same error

Answer (score 0):

The process described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366822/naming-clipped-layer-according-to-the-attributes-of-the-mask-layer-in-qgis) might help you too. The key point is after `Raster -> Extraction -> Clip raster by mask layer`, you need to click on the little circulation sign:

[image]

Bigger picture:

[image]

Output: separate raster layers.

[image]